# Show / Hide DatePicker tapping on a TextField

Tags: xcode, swift, datepicker, ios8

I have a profile view, where there are 4 TextField, in one of which must be inserted the date using a DatePicker, I realized, though, that this DatePicker is always visible, on the other hand I would like to appear when you click on the TextField that contains the date. How can I fix?
The code that I inserted is this:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var bornDate: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateSec: UIDatePicker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dateSec.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateSec.date)
    bornDate.text = strDate
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem with the date format by inserting this piece of code:

```
  var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"     
       let d = NSDate()     
       let s = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d)               
       println(s)
```